# Migration from IBM VisualAge C++ 3.6.5 to VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-age

We're in the process of migrating 32-bit C++ application to 64-bit application (VS 2010). This application was developed 10 years back with IBM VisualAge C++ 3.6.5 for Windows. Since IBM has stopped support of this compiler, we're facing issues while migrating it to VS 2010.

This is mostly because of some missing libraries.

Sample errors:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __uopen referenced in function "int __cdecl allocate_heap_storage_(void)" (?allocate_heap_storage@@YAHXZ)
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __ucreate referenced in function "int __cdecl allocate_heap_storage_(void)" (?allocate_heap_storage@@YAHXZ)
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __udestory referenced in function "int __cdecl deallocate_heap_storage_(void)" (?deallocate_heap_storage@@YAHXXZ)
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __uclose referenced in function "int __cdecl deallocate_heap_storage_(void)" (?deallocate_heap_storage@@YAHXXZ)
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __umalloc referenced in function "int __cdecl alloc_share_mem_(int,int)" (?alloc_share_mem@YAPAXHH@Z)

The above functions are defined in umalloc.h but we are missing the definitions.

How can we resolve this?

Comment: Is there maybe a source you're not building with?

Comment: Something of interest about this is that you might not even be able to legitimately reimplement the user heap library (`libhu.a`) for these functions - it appears to be patented: http://www.ptodirect.com/Patents/6816956  I would have thought that there was plenty of prior art covering this kind of thing.  If nothing else, Win32 supported multiple process-level heaps since WinNT 3.5 (which I'd expect was something Cutler, et al, borrowed from VMS).

Answer (score 0):

For the errors above, these function "_*ucreate",*_udestory , _*uclose,*_umalloc" are not found when linking, I think these functions were in the run time libraries provided by Visual Age. if you can find the lib files of the these run time libraries, you can put them in the input of link, it may pass the compiling phase, but may fail to launch.

One suggestion here is to replace the functions above with windows functions. All the functions above are related with memory allocations.